# Python: nice way to access all metadata data in PGK-INFO?

Tags: python, hash, egg

I want to include an MD5 hash of my source code whenever I install my module. To do this I put the hash at the end of the description field for setuptools.setup:

```
import subprocess
cmd="/sbin/md5 mymodule/*.py | md5 "
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
hash=p.stdout.read().strip().decode()
print(hash)

from setuptools import setup

setup(name='mymodule',
      version='0.1',
      packages=['mymodule', ],
      description = "My awesome Module. \nsourcehash="+hash+"\n",

  )
```

Then in my **__*init*__**.py, I include:

```
import os.path
with open(os.path.split(__file__)[0]+'/../EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO', 'r') as f:
    pkg_info=f.read()
__sourcehash__ = pkg_info.split('sourcehash=')[1][:32]
```

This works, but it feels hacky. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `hashlib.md5(open('myfile.py', 'rb').read()).hexdigest()`

Comment: I'm more worried about the code in ____init____.py

Comment: You didn't specify anything at all to be honest that you thought was "hacky", and to me calling an external application to do md5 sums is the most hacky things of them all in this code so..